# How can I enter commands in plain text in Mathematica11?

Tags: front-end, input

[image]

I tried to type $Pi * 9 ^ 2$ and hit Shift+Enter.

Nothing happened other than a ding sound.

[image]

How can I enter commands in plain text in Mathematica11?

Comment: You don't. You don't use this mode for entering commands. This mode is just for typing out text. Don't use it.

Comment: Click on "Wolfram Language Input" or just click in the notebook and start typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we open a new notebook in the front end, we get that gray line with the plus sign in the upper left corner, as you show.  We click the plus sign and get the drop-down menu, as you show.  Now we have some options.

**Wolfram Language Input** -- this first option on the drop-down just opens an input cell for use.  We don't need to open the drop-down, though, since this is the default action when we start typing.

**Free-form input** -- means we want to type input like "five times three" and MMA should interpret that semantically and return "15", which it does, if there is an internet connection that can reach the WolframAlpha servers.  Another command, "integrate x", is also interpreted semantically, but MMA does not return the best answer.  For more complicated input like "where is the red sea?" and "what color is the red sea?" the answers are not so great.

**Wolfram | Alpha input** -- means what we type in will be sent to WA for interpretation.  Here we can type in "integrate x" and get a much better answer.  WA knows more about the red sea, too.

**Plain text** -- means what we enter should be considered as plain text, *not* as commands to be interpreted.  MMA just puts that input in a text box for us to read.  We use this mode for writing the text part of our notebooks.

**Other style of text** -- this option opens a little dialog window in which we can type the name of the style we want for the cell.  The default is the "item" style, but we can type in, for example, "Chapter" to insert a cell with that style.

Note that there are short cuts to the free-form inputs.  Instead of clicking that plus sign to get the drop-down menu, press the equals sign once for free-form input, a second time for WA input and a third time for regular input to the front end.  We can also backspace over the shortcuts when we accidentally hit the equals sign at the wrong time.